# Why is the cyclic decomposition of a primary torsion module not unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

It is known that a finitely generated torsion module $M$ over a principal ideal domain $R$ can be decomposed into a direct sum of primary modules,
$$
M=M_{p_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus M_{p_n}.
$$
Futhermore, the primary submodules $M_{p_i}$ can be decomposed as a direct sum of cyclic submodules, but this decomposition is not unique.

Is there a standard example exhibiting why the cyclic decomposition of a primary module is not unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, consider an abelian group of order $4$, written additively, which is the sum
$$
\langle a \rangle \oplus \langle b \rangle,
$$
with $a$ and $b$ of order $2$. Then you also have
$$
\langle a+b \rangle \oplus \langle b \rangle.
$$
So you see that this is just the fact that in general a vector space (over $\mathbf{Z}_{2}$, in this case) does not have a unique basis.