# Understanding $P_i$ primary component.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

From Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote, after proving [image]

It says the following.

[image]

In class, we defined $N_i$ to be the $p_i$-primary component of $M$. But I'm having trouble understanding what grouping all the cyclic factors corresponding to the same prime $p_i$.

My guess is that in the decomposition, we get primes $p_1, \ldots p_t$. And out of those, we pick out distinct $p_1, \ldots p_n$. And do we say $N_i = R/(p_i^{\alpha_s}) \oplus \ldots \oplus R/(p_i^{\alpha_k})$? And is there no more simplification possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. You let $N_i$ be the direct sum of those components corresponding to the prime $p_i$ (where the $p_i$ are now *distinct* primes).  There is no more simplification possible.

One thing to be careful of: The $N_i$ are uniquely determined by the group $M$, but the components within an $N_i$ are not uniquely determined.  For example, there are many ways to decompose $\mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z}$ as a direct sum of that form.

Comment: Thanks! But isn't the only possible way to decompose $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ just setting $N_1 = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: There are two decompositions, the "coarser" one in terms of the $N_i$ (the one you mentioned second in your post, where all the primes are distinct), and the finer one where each $N_i$ is decomposed further (the one mentioned first in your post, in the statement of the theorem, where the primes need not be distinct).  The coarser decomposition is unique.  The finer decomposition is not.

Comment: is this along the line of what you mean? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312184/why-is-the-cyclic-decomposition-of-a-primary-torsion-module-not-unique?rq=1

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean.